# Change data cutoff frequency over time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data with this structure
[image]

Is there a way to change data cutoff frequency over time (on python side, not SQL) from 30-min slice to 1 hour,
with an obligatory condition when changing slices, sum the value in the columns 'starts' and 'scooter_on_parking', but the rest of the values ​​should not change. Basic command

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1H', key='time_')).sum()
```

sums all columns, how to leave part unchanged - don't quite understand.
Thank.

Update: answer

```
new_df = ( df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1H', key='time_')).agg({'starts':'sum', 
                               'scooters_on_parking':'sum'}).reset_index() )
new_df = new_df.merge(df, on='time_'
```

did not fit, the data is incorrect - after aggregation, the data diverges greatly.

**Example of actual values**
[image].

**The result**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since after `groupby` you need an `aggregation` operation, the easiest way to apply a function to only some columns would be to use `merge` after `groupby`:

```
new_df = ( df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1H', key='time_')).agg({'starts':'sum', 
                               'scooters_on_parking':'sum'}).reset_index() )
new_df = new_df.merge(df, on='time_')
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't fit, description above